# Increment a variable inside a loop

Tags: python

I want to track the number of times loop was executed.And,when it has been executed more than x times,do something.The below code does not work;The variable a is always 0

```
bup = set(line.strip() for line in open('C://Users/'+username+'/Desktop/manifest.backup'))
orig = set(line.strip() for line in open(direc.replace('/something','')+'/manifest.json'))

for line in bup & orig:
    if line:
        if line[0] is '"':
            a = 0
            if line[1] is 'b':
                print('strings that start with b match!')
                break
            else:
                print(len(set(bup) & set(orig)))
                print(line)
                print(a)
                a = a + 1
                if a >= (len(set(bup) & set(orig))-2):
                    print('Conclusion')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you keep on resetting `a` to 0 at the beginning of every loop. Move the line `a = 0` outside the loop (before the `for`).